# Why Git suggest "changes" to me on a (theoretically) ignored file (path)?

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-2015

I'm using VS2015 GitHub extension, on a repositary I own (forked, really).
Within the `.gitignore` file at some point I've this (taken from the fork, I didn't add myself that `ignore`):

```
...

VST3_SDK/*

...
```

but on VS2015 it seems to suggest a file within that folder has been "edited", and need to be staged:

[image]

I don't want this of course. These files/path should be "ignored" from versioning.

Where am I wrong?

EDIT: I don't want "workaround" to ignore it. I don't want to git it anymore...

Comment: Did you add the excluding pattern to your `.gitignore` _after_ this file was already in the repository?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ignore files that have already been committed to a Git repository](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139762/ignore-files-that-have-already-been-committed-to-a-git-repository)

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: no its not the same. Check the answer below...

Comment: (after reading answers and comments) : have you tried `git reset VST3_SDK` ?

Comment: @LeGEC: yes, nothing happens!

Comment: You might want to check whether the problem is within `git` by running `git check-ignore -v <your file>`. If that outputs something, the problem is not within `git`, if it doesn't report the file as ignored, you should check why it cannot match the file with your `.gitignore` pattern.

Comment: Btw: Where is your .gitignore file located relative to the VST3_SDK directory?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems the file was committed once (maybe before it was ignored, maybe someone forced Git to start tracking it).

You can remove the file from Git (but not your harddrive) using

```
git rm --cached VST3_SDT/base/win/base_vc10.vcxproj.user
```

Afterwards, instead of "modified" the file will appear as "deleted". This is expected and should be committed (this commit will fix the issue for all other developers on this project, too). Afterwards Git will ignore the file for you and everybody else.

Comment: it says `fatal: VST3_SDK\base\win\base_vc10.vcxproj.user is outside repository`

Comment: Umm... can you post the git root path, and the path of the offending file?

Comment: The "offending" file its not on the repository, since I don't want to stage it :)

Comment: Ah so it wasn't tracked before. Can you try changing the `.gitignore` line to `VST3_SDK/**`?

Comment: Tried right now! Nothing change, visual studio still tell me the file has changed :(

Answer (score 6):

**.gitignore** works for files that are *not* part of the project yet. If a file is already part of the project (it is part of HEAD already) then .the file being part of .gitignore does not matter. If this file is already part of the project and you still don't want to see it as modified (weird, but possible) then you have to use **git update-index** to tell git to just not care about it.

Comment: Thinking about it, I'm wondering if libgit2 (the library used by VS's implementation of git, right?) actually resembles native git's behavior (which is what I described on my comment).

Comment: So what should I do?

Comment: If the file is already _in_ the project but you actually don't care if the file changes, then ask git to not care about it:

    git update-index --assume-unchanged blah/blah/blah.txt

That should be enough.

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-update-index

Comment: Uhm, that's a workaround! I don't want to "ignore it", but remove it from gitting...

Comment: Well... you could then ```git rm --cache``` it so that it goes away from git (while still keeping it on your working tree.... and if it's in git ignore git won't tell you anything about it after you commit it)... or you could go back in history and rewrite the history so that the file is not on any previous commit.

Answer (score 0):

You ignore directories and everything inside/below them like this:

```
VST3_SDK/
```

Do not use `*` at the end.

Answer (score -1):

There is a bug in VS2015 (and VS2013) which causes some `.gitignore` rules to not be adhered to.

### Solution 1:

Try searching for the file `.git\ms-persist.xml` within your solution directory and deleting it (you may have to ensure you can see hidden files and folders). Once you restart Visual Studio, it will re-read your `.gitignore` (regenerating `ms-persist.xml`) and should stop tracking the ignored file(s).

### <s>Solution 2</s> Workaround:

If this doesn't solve your problem, the next step would be to explicitly declare the file you don't want tracked in your `.gitignore`:

```
...
VST3_SDK/*
VST3_SDK/base/win/base_vc10.vcxproj.user
...
```

Comment: Solution 1 doesn't works! Solution 2 is not a solution, but a workaround.